# Find every file that has a specific word in the last line, and output the files into a new file

Tags: bash

I am trying to ouput every file that in it's last line has #FIXME and output the files that do into a new file. I've tried various ways of doing the last step however I can't get it right. Nothing gets put into the new file

this is what i've been trying

```
find -type f -print0 |while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
tail -n1 "$file" | grep -q FIXME &&  "$file" > newlog.log 
done
```

thanks for the help

Comment: You're almost there, add an `echo` before the `"$file"` after the `&&`

Comment: Thank you. I swear I was doing that before but thank you!